# In react-router, why should the common elements of the page be children of the Router?

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

In [the 1st, basic example in the quickstart](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start/1st-example-basic-routing), they [include the `nav` (which is common to all routes) in the `Router`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blame/b529499efcb906c814b9a3a68e2b4292a15b09c8/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/quick-start.md#L41) (pasted below for convenience). I can't tell from the code that this is necessary or preferable.

**Must I/is it somehow best to likewise put my common components/elements inside the `Router`?**

I suspect this was this simply shorthand to avoid wrapping multiple elements in the return from `render` (implicit `render` in this case).

```js
// ...

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I found my answer .

If the common elements/components do not require use of any other `react-router` components, it should be ok to move them outside. In the linked example, the `nav` uses the react-router `Link` component, and so [should be inside `Router`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/b529499efcb906c814b9a3a68e2b4292a15b09c8/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js#L88) (same is true for other react-router components, e.g. [`Route`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/b529499efcb906c814b9a3a68e2b4292a15b09c8/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L35)